# C++: macro expansion explanation

Tags: c++, macros

I am reading a C++ header file, in which there writes:

```
 class CLASSEXPORT skExecutable : {.....}
```

A comment says that CLASSEXPORT is a macro expansion and then I find where CLASSEXPORT is defined.

```
 #define CLASSEXPORT
```

And that's all..I feel confused about this..What does CLASSEXPORT represent in this sense? And how to understand the class skExecutable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `CLASSEXPORT` is expanded to nothing (probably because it is not needed to expand it into something meaningful in your exact configuration), so your class will just be a `class skExecutable {<...>};`. This approach is commonly used for import/export directives, e.g. in the following snippet an appropriate directive will be places depending on whether `COMPILING_DLL` macro is defined:

```
#if COMPILING_DLL
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLLEXPORT MyClass
{
};
```

Comment: You didn't really answer the question. You should note that your answer is platform specific. On linux etc. there is no need to write __declspec(dllexport) to export a symbol. The reason the macro is empty may be that he is running on linux and this is a cross platform code and the macro should evaluate empty. The class will be exported anyway.

Comment: @SebastianCabot, the example with dllexport is just an example. The OP's macro can do anything at all, and I have no idea what is it's intended purpose when it is not empty.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! @SingerOfTheFall I think your answer and dandan's answer can be combined as one excellent answer!

Comment: His question was why it is empty

Comment: @SebastianCabot thanks for your comments, but actually Singer answers my question

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear some stuff up: `CLASSEXPORT` is a *macro*. *Macro expansion* is a process, performed prior to compilation, during which all macros are replaced with whatever they are defined as.

In your case, I suspect that `CLASSEXPORT` is there to allow all classes that are declared in that way to be exported to some kind of shared library if the need arises in the future. Then that `CLASSEXPORT` would be defined as something like

```
#define CLASSEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
```

and you could use `skExecutable` directly from a shared library.

Comment: You didn't really answer the question. You should note that your answer is platform specific. On linux etc. there is no need to write __declspec(dllexport) to export a symbol. The reason the macro is empty may be that he is running on linux and this is a cross platform code and the macro should evaluate empty. The class will be exported anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think SingerOfTheFall's answer and your answer should be combined as one excellent answer haha

Comment: @dandan78 I tick Singer's answer, not because your answer is not good, but Singer's answer is more to my question and he receives more votes. I really like your answer, which helps me to clarify more problems. I hope you understand

Comment: @gladys0313 Don't worry about it. How you vote is completely up to you. His answer is probably better anyway.